# HostingEnviroment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem works on localhost but cancels on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, queue

I want the server to update a user by mail and because mailing takes around 5 seconds I want to run this on the background thread. The problem is IIS cancels my backgroundoperation before it can finish.

The following code works when I test in visual studio but doesn't work when I test on windows server:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => ProgressMail(ct, smtpSend, emailMessage));
```

and my progressmail method is as follows:

```
private static void ProgressMail(CancellationToken ct, SmtpClient client, MailMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error("Error sending mail in background thread", ex);
    }
}
```

Microsoft documentation on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx) states the following:

> Differs from a normal ThreadPool work item in that ASP.NET can keep track of how many work items registered through this API are currently running, and the ASP.NET runtime will try to delay AppDomain shutdown until these work items have finished executing. This API cannot be called outside of an ASP.NET-managed AppDomain. The provided CancellationToken will be signaled when the application is shutting down.

ASP.NET Runtime will try to delay shutdown. But its still shutting down. What am I doing wrong here? How can I force my application to keep running even when the request is finished.

Comment: I have never experienced something like this. "Cancels your background operation" means that the exception handler is hit with a respective ``OperationCanceledException``?

Comment: the exception ex is null

Comment: What makes you think the operation is canceled then? How did you confirm this?

Comment: I assumed it dit, because the client.send(message) works on both local machine and windows server but when putting the code in QueueBackgroundWorkItem() the logger is hit, but only on windows server.

Comment: How can the exception be null then? If you do not know what exception causes the error you should probably investigate the issue deeply instead of *assuming* that it is caused by cancellation. There is a 50/50 chance that your send method throws as well.

Comment: Will investigate further. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Just a thought: Maybe you're disposing the ``SmtpClient`` too early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Peit I knew to look more closely at `SMTPClient` and not at the 
`HostingEnviroment.QueueBackgroundItem()`

Problem was in sending email with SMTP on IIS. Had to add:

```
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

And now it's working on both localhost and IIS :)